# Typescript for in loop, iterate through union type of object or array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use the `for in loop` over union type of either object or array, since arrays are objects as well and their key property is the index.

```js
const loopOver = (question: any[] | {[key: string]: any} ) => {
  for (let key in question) { // error ts 7053
    console.log(question[key])
  }
};
```

results in error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'any[] | { [key: string]: any; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'any[] | { [key: string]: any; }'.ts(7053)
```

but once I remove the union type and leave it to either object or array, then I don't get any errors.

```
// okay
const loopOver = (question: {[key: string]: any} ) => {
  for (let key in question) {
    console.log(question[key])
  }
};
// okay
const loopOver = (question: any[] ) => {
  for (let key in question) { 
    console.log(question[key])
  }
};
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

ts version in package.json `^3.8.3`

Comment: upgrade ts to Version 3.7.5 or above

Comment: The type `[]` is specifically a zero-length array.  Perhaps you mean `any[]` instead?

Comment: @xdeepakv I upgraded to 3.8.3 and it didn't solve my problem.
@jcalz I expected any type of array, empty or has any elements. Changing `[]` to `any[]` didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays should be indexed with *numbers*, not strings. But `for..in` iterates *strings* - your `key` is a string. When looking up properties on the array, cast the string key to a number for it to work. (But when looking up the property on the object, since the object uses `[key: string]: any`, you have to keep looking up using the string)

```
const loopOver = (question: [] | {[key: string]: any} ) => {
  for (let key in question) {
    if (Array.isArray(question)) {
      console.log(question[Number(key)])
    } else {
      console.log(question[key])
    }
  }
};
```

But, from this code, it looks like you don't actually care about the keys at all (and [for..in should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) be used with arrays anyway). You only care about the values, so how about using `Object.values` instead?

```
const loopOver = (question: [] | {[key: string]: any} ) => {
  for (const val of Object.values(question)) {
    console.log(val)
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that the type `[]` is specifically the zero-tuple, an array with no elements.  So there'd be no reason to loop over that at all.  Presumably the OP means `any[]` or something similar, though.